# How to use Firebase Auth and Facebook login together?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am completely new to Flutter/Dart so pardon my lack of knowledge.

I am trying to set up a login page in my app. I would like to use Firebase Auth as it supports a wide range of authentication options. However, I want to start with Facebook for which I am using the following different dart plugin

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login

I don't think the official flutter plugin for Firebase auth does not support Facebook login yet. My plan is to somehow combine the two to get the following

1. Use the `flutter_facebook_login` plugin to perform the login using facebook and get facebook access token
2. Pass the facebook access token to Firebase Auth to register a user from a custom token

However, when I pass FB access token to Firebase Auth, I get an error that the access token is malformed. Has anyone done this before?

I want to use Firebase Auth to persist the user's login session as long as possible and when the access token runs out use the refresh token to get a new access token. This will essentially mean that once the user logs in using Facebook, they will be permanently logged into my app.